# Size of image in rtf file

Tags: c#, image, performance, rtf, image-size

When I copy and paste an image to a richtextbox and save it into rtf file (using `SaveFile()`), the size is much larger than the size of the image (about 10 times larger).

Is there a way to reduce the size of rtf files?

Answer (score 0):

No it is not possible to reduce image size of RTF files because RTF is saving a image in WMF (Windows Metafile), uncompressed format so the image size is big. You can only zip/rar the whole file to get less file size.